# How to check if credentials valid on a remote repository with LibGit2Sharp library

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am working with LibGit2Sharp lib and i need to ping a remote and check if provided credentials valid.

Most of the samples provided https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/LibGit2Sharp-Hitchhiker%27s-Guide-to-Git here require a local folder to create a Repository object. I think it is not best practice to create tmp folder and then try to fetch data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to retrieve the list of remote references of the distant repository through the static  `Repository.ListRemoteReferences()` method.

This would not download the content of the repository on your disk as everything would be dealt with in memory.

See the **[`CanListRemoteReferencesWithCredentials()`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RepositoryFixture.cs#L692-L705)** unit test for additional help regarding usage.

Comment: if repo is public it returns refs anyway? can I find out if the repo was public?

Comment: You don't need to provide any credential to retrieve the remote references from a public repository.